# Transit in Toronto from US to Europe on Air Canada

Tags: transit, toronto, yyz

I am going back from 14 days US vacation to Germany via Denmark, flying on Air Canada from Newark, transferring in Toronto and leaving Toronto to Copenhagen (CPH) on Air Canada 4 hours later. Both AC flights are on the same ticket and I am German. On a separate Star Alliance ticket (Scandinavian Airlines), I will fly from CPH to Germany after 2 hours layover in CPH.

1. Will I be able to check my luggage through to Denmark or Germany from New York? Don't think so, because from Toronto Airport Website I understood, that I will have to gather and recheck my luggage.
2. I have read on a forum, that at Toronto Terminal I might get ["locked" in an area](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/24130925-post18.html), from where it is impossible to go to the Maple Leaf Lounge until it is time to go to customs and security. Did I misunderstand or might something similar be possible?

Comment: @pnuts,I`m talking about this :http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/24130925-post18.html

Comment: @pnuts,thanks for your answer,but I think I`ll try now in a German forum,because perhaps my English really isn`t good enough to put my question in a way everyone can follow me.You seem to be the only one.

Comment: This does not feel like a duplicate. It's actually rather complicated. Canadian airports do NOT have a concept of transit. You have to immigrate into Canada first. See http://www.torontopearson.com/Connecting_from_usa.aspx# . It's unclear whether you bags get tagged through or whether Canadian customs wants to see them. Check with the airline. You will have to collect your bags in CPH and do a full check in for the flight to Germany

Comment: @pnuts,thanks for your words of encouragement concerning my English,but as the post by Hilmar shows,transfer seems to be pretty tricky and I`ll make a call to AC.

Comment: @Hilmar,thank you for convincing me not to search for answers to questions no one can answer,as there simply seems to be no rule.Collecting the bags in CPH is no problem-small airport and time enough